# How to change image of activated button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to change image of button when button is activated.

For example you can change colour of activated button

```
from tkinter import *   
win = Tk()
but = Button(win, text="Show Image on Activate", activebackground="red")
but.pack()
```

Comment: Added sample working code

Answer (score 0):

There is no `activeimage` property, so you have to get around. The basic idea is to change the `image` property of the Button when it is activated. Here is the general principle:

```
from tkinter import *

def activate():
    but['image'] = images[1] # switch image

win = Tk()
images = (PhotoImage(file="a.gif"), PhotoImage(file="b.gif"))
but = Button(win, image=images[0], command=activate)
but.pack()
win.mainloop()
```